# Jhipster application error first run

Tags: javascript, node.js, jhipster, yo

After generationg successfully a new Jshipster 3 application, I'm having trouble to serve the application using `gulp serve`.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and `npm 3.9` and when I try to run `gulp serve`, I get this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cw61N.png)

And when I access `http://localhost:9000/` I get the following message on the browser:

```
    Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
   at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
   at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
   at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1063:14)
```

Any advices? :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error says that **gulp cannot connect to the backend** on the `127.0.0.1:8080` address, which most likely mean that you haven't started the backend.

**You should start the Spring application** using the `mvn spring-boot:run` or `mvn` command, which starts the application on the `http://localhost:8080` address.

Read more here: https://jhipster.github.io/development/

Answer (score 0):

add @ComponentScan annotation and base package name

@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.example"})

see below code.

```
package com.example.SampleProject;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.example"})

public class SampleProjectApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SampleProjectApplication.class, args);
  }

}
```